# Advise a dummy on how to structure my query and set up my mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Pardon me if this looks too basic, I am just a beginner in springboot. I am trying to create a simple project. I have entity class "`company.java`" and another "`jobs.java`"

I have already mapped them such that it will be saving both "companyID,jobID"
now my question is here :

1) how can I ensure that the record is captured into that new table when i feed data from thymeleaf fields. I have tried a dummy entry and its saving jobs into the jobs table but its not capturing anything to insert into the joined table

2) How do I query such that it saves and also when I search a job by its ID it shows me the company.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_account")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@SecondaryTable(name = "company_profile")
public class CompanyAccount {
    private int id;
    private String CompanyName;
    private String PhoneNumber;
    private String Number_of_employees;
    private String CompanyURL;
    private String OrganisationType;
    private String PrimaryIndustry;
    private byte[] Logo;
    private String Location;
    private String DateEstablished;
    private String Headquarters;
    private String SocialMedia;


    public CompanyAccount() {
    }

///////////////////////here i tried the mapping


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company_account")
    private List<NewJobs> jobs = new ArrayList<NewJobs>();


    @Id
    // @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault("001")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////
deleted the getters and setters

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "newjobs")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class NewJobs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault("001")
    private int newjobid;

    public NewJobs() {
    }
```

tried my mapping here

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "company_account")
    @JoinTable(name = "company_jobs", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "newjobid") })
    private CompanyAccount CompanyAccount;
}
```

How can I query my insert and also my search by id ?

Comment: Are you using any **class** which is **implementing* a `Repository` interface. Maybe a `CrudRepository`

Comment: yes i have ...service,repository and controller.....i want to send an object to the thymeleaf

Comment: You can do that by adding your object to the model of the controller and then return a thymeleaf view. Then you can access that object in th thymeleaf view with special thymeleaf tags such as `th:text` or `th:object`